# JVM bytecode limitations on class-class interactions

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

I was looking through the [JVM bytecode instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) and was surprised to see that all the interactions between classes (e.g. casting, `new`, etc.) rely upon constant pool lookups for identity of the other classes.

Am I correct in inferring that this means that one class cannot know about the existence of more than 64k others, as it is impossible to refer to them?  If one did need to refer to that many, what ought one do--delegate the work to multiple classes each of which could have their own <64k interactions?

(The reason this interests me is that I have a habit of writing code generators, sometimes producing thousands of distinct classes, and that some languages (e.g. Scala) create classes prolifically.  So it seems that if true I have to be careful: if I have hundreds of methods in a class each using hundreds of (distinct) classes, I could exceed the constant pool space.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I correct in inferring that this means that one class cannot know about the existence of more than 64k others, as it is impossible to refer to them?

I think you are correct.  And don't forget that there are constant pool entries for other things; e.g. all of the classes method and fields names, and all of its literal strings.

> If one did need to refer to that many, what ought one do--delegate the work to multiple classes each of which could have their own <64k interactions?

I guess so.

However, I'm not convinced that this *concern* would ever be realized in practice.  It is hard to conceive of a class that *needs* to directly interact with that many other classes ... unless the code generator is ignoring the structure of its input source code.

Comment: If you have a ridiculous number of classes for computing various specialized primitive operations on small vectors and matrices (where the classes are the same save for using different primitives to hold different elements), and try to create one organizer class that will take object arrays and debox them for processing using that forest of specialized classes, you can get alarmingly close to the limit.  I think the bigger answer is still "don't do it that way" as I have to go to a lot of trouble stuffing bytes back into bytes after doing math on them.  But I never imagined I'd break the JVM.

Comment: If you are generating specialized code for performance reasons, and you end up creating thousands of classes, you might want to rethink your approach.  You will end up incurring a lot of extra overhead for class loading, verification, JIT, etc.

Comment: And the same applies to generating thousands of methods in one class.  But either way, there are all sorts of "premature optimization" issues here; e.g. the decision to generate / use different versions for different primitive types.  Is it really going to make enough difference to be worth the hassle?  And are you really going to need to generate so many of these things?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your problem could be solved via `invokedynamic`. This is basically a much faster form of reflection designed to ease the implementation of dynamic languages on the JVM.

If you really do have to deal with thousands of automatically generated classes, you probably don't want to statically link it all. Just use `invokedynamic`. This also has the advantage of letting you defer some code generation to runtime.

Note that you still need a constant pool entry for every dynamic method called by a class, but you no longer need to refer to the actual class and methods being called. In fact, you can create them on demand.

Comment: I heard if you `invokedynamic` on yourself, hair grows on your keyboard.

Comment: @Rex, no you can call any method with it. In fact, you can apply wrappers for autoboxing and currying too. It works by calling an associated `java.lang.invoke.CallSite` instance which is created the first time the instruction executes via a bootstrap method. So it's basically a function pointer with less overhead than traditional reflection.